# NFTs on anchor tests

Tags: anchor, metaplex, anchor-lang, anchor-test, anchor-client

I'm trying to use [this](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/nfts/how-to-mint-an-nft-on-solana-using-typescript#upload-metadata) guide to create an NFT to test with my anchor program. When I attempt to mint the NFT, I am met with the following error.

```
FailedToSendTransactionError: The transaction could not be sent successfully to the network. Please check the underlying error below for more details.

Caused By: Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Attempt to load a program that does not exist
```

my connection is `program.provider.connection`, and I'm not sure what to do differently.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the Metaplex metadata program is not present in your testing environment. You can dump the program by running:

```
solana program dump metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s mpl_token_metadata.so
```

And then add it to a test validator by running:

```
solana-test-validator --bpf-program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s mpl_token_metadata.so
```